# CSS right float can't change size and sizes doesn't match css

Tags: css, sass

When i try to make a 1x1x1 field with 2 divs in each field with help of flex the size doesn't change i want it to be 33.33% width on left, middle and right side but it doesn't seem to work.
Summary: 
I would like left, middle and right div to have an equal width.

I've tried changing widths and tried flexbox but this seemed like the best solution if i get it to work.

{HTML}

```
<section class="Sec-Settings">
        <div class="Settings">
            <div class="left-float">
                <div class="profile-img">
                    <p style="margin:0;">Profile Img</p>
                </div>
                <div class="profile-name">
                    <p style="margin:0;">Profile Name</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="middle-float">
                <div class="account-information">
                    <p style="margin:0;">Account Information</p>
                </div>
                <div class="delete-account">
                    <p style="margin:0;">Delete Account</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="change-account-information">
                    <p style="margin:0;">Change Account Information</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

{/HTML}

{CSS}

```
.Sec-Settings {
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings {
  margin: auto;
  width: 96vw;
  height: 86vh;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings .left-float,
.Sec-Settings .Settings .middle-float,
.Sec-Settings .Settings .right-float {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings .middle-float {
  width: 30vw;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings .right-float {
  width: 30vw;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings .middle-float {
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings .profile-img {
  height: 33.33%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  background-color: dimgray;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings .profile-name {
  height: 66.77%;
  width: 33.33%;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings .account-information {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a71515;
}

.Sec-Settings .Settings .change-account-information {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a71515;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .Sec-Settings {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .Sec-Settings .Settings {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

{/CSS}

Also have the scss if that's easier to read

{SCSS}

```
.Sec-Settings {
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: auto;


  .Settings {
    margin: auto;
    width: 96vw;
    height: 86vh;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 10px 10px;
    // padding: 6px;
    // padding-left: 15px;
    // padding-top: 7px;
    display: flex;

    .left-float,
    .middle-float,
    .right-float {
      flex: 1;
    }

    // .left-float,
    // .right-float,
    // .middle-float {
    //   width: 33.33%;
    // }

    .middle-float {
      width: 30vw;
    }

    .right-float {
      width: 30vw;
    }

    .middle-float {
      margin: 0 3px;
    }


    .profile-img {
      height: 33.33%;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
      background-color: dimgray;
    }

    .profile-name {
      height: 66.77%;
      width: 33.33%;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
      background-color: #1a1a1a;
    }

    .account-information {
      height: 90%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #a71515;
    }

    .change-account-information {
      height: 90%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #a71515;
    }

    .delete-account {

    }
  }
}
```

{/SCSS}

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to achieve an equal-width column layout with flex. I prefer the first method here that uses `justify-content:stretch;` so you can use the same setup regardless of the number of columns.

Set the parent to `display:flex; justify-content: stretch;` and set the children to `flex: 1;`

Set the parent to `display:flex;` and use the width to set the flex-basis on the children to `flex: 1 0 33.33%;`

```css
.Settings {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.Settings>div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Settings">
  <div class="left-float">
    <div class="profile-img">
      <p style="margin:0;">Profile Img</p>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-name">
      <p style="margin:0;">Profile Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-float">
    <div class="account-information">
      <p style="margin:0;">Account Information</p>
    </div>
    <div class="delete-account">
      <p style="margin:0;">Delete Account</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="change-account-information">
      <p style="margin:0;">Change Account Information</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your last column class only says "right" instead of "right-float" so your css is not being applied.

1. Give all 3 columns a common class to target. (E.g. "float")
2. .float { flex-basis: 33.33%; flex: 1; }

Flex-basis will tell all the columns to start at 1/3 width and flex:1 will  tell them all to expand at the same speed and cover any leftover pixels from weird screen sizes.